# when node js is running in the machine connected to network by wifi can't access it from other devices

Tags: node.js, express

When i run this node js code in a pc connected the network by lan (wired) i can connect to this server from other devices on same network, but when i run this servr on pc with wifi connection(same network as the former) i cannot connect to this server from other devices but can connect only from the same pc where the server is running. please help.

````
const api = express();
api.get('/', (request, response) => response.send(`hello!`));
api.listen(5000, '192.168.1.3', () => console.info('api running'));```
````

Comment: Is the WiFi connection a "guest" connection that has no access to the local network?  Many routers have such a feature.  If so, that would keep it off the local network and only allow it to access the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the WIFI connection has the SAME IP address as the LAN connection?

(run IPCONFIG at command prompt if you're running a PC)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the host `0.0.0.0`. Once you configured this `host` you should be able to access the computer using the computer IP.

Usually works, given that most of the time the `localhost` is not accessible through the `ip`.